# Can I say "Oh boy" to a girl?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, phrase-request, phrase-choice, idiom-request

I've known that "Oh boy" is similar to "Oh my goodness", but can I use it when speaking to a girl?

Also, what are the popular alternatives?

Comment: Exclamatory *Oh boy!* is even more "dated" than *[Oh] man!*. I suggest you avoid them both, but I don't think the literal gender reference of the words themselves has any relevance to the sex of the speaker, or whoever they might be addressing.

Comment: @FumbleFingers What're the recommended alternatives?

Comment: *Gosh! Wow! Crumbs! Golly! Land sakes and lawks a mussy!* - there are any number of such exclamations. Most of them are at least "dated", if not positively "antiquated". But I suggest you copy whatever the people (ideally, of about your own age) around you say ***today***, rather than what you might find in books written decades or centuries ago.

Comment: I used to work with a Welsh guy who had spent several years teaching in Bermuda before coming back the the UK. It was quite normal for him to start a phone call by saying (in a Welsh accent!) "Hi Brenda man, is Susan man there?"

Comment: It's probably similar to asking whether you can say "OMG" (the less polite one) when not speaking to God.

Comment: @Wenfang It depends on the context. I use "oh boy" pretty often in a negative context, where, depending on the situation, I could replace it with "oh no", "welp", "oof", "ugh", "yikes", or "aw man". If you're using it in a positive context, that sounds more dated to me, but I'd replace it with like, "nice", "alright", "hell yeah", or "sweet". For context, I'm a millennial Maritimer, although some of these might be a bit idiosyncratic, idk.

Comment: Let's not even get started on "Oh man!"

Comment: I suggest rather than using dated expressions, or showing yourself to be overly conventional by using the current vernacular, you show yourself to be ahead of the times by using the exclamations of the _future_: "Streets ahead!" (for good things) and "Streets behind!" (for bad things).

Comment: Holy cow, people sure are down on saying oh boy all of a sudden.

Comment: I think usage of "oh boy" must vary by location.  I am quite sure that in Philadelphia, where I live, it is still common, and does not sound dated or fussy.

Comment: People say "Oh god" when they are not speaking to a god

Comment: I am not sure why *Oh Boy* is being called dated.  Who says it's dated?  Uncommon, yes.  Dated?  I would not call it that.

Comment: @WenfangDu - How are you planning to use it when speaking to a girl?  It's an exclamation, generally directed at whoever may be listening.  It's like *For Pete's Sake!*, which does not require a *Pete* to be present or known before it's said.

Comment: Funnily enough, this is a very common slang in some areas of Brazil - just like, in english and everything. It usually carries the meaning of "oh no" over here.

Comment: Oh-boy-haters need a dose of Allan Sherman. Notice how expressive the phrase is. (OK, some of the other references in the song *are* a bit dated!) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2dgr1bV1CtQ

Comment: I always wondered if "Oh boy" was an Americanization of "Oy Vey".

Comment: A followup to my earlier comment: I was telling my kids (ages 13 and 17) about this discussion, and I couldn't remember what phrase was supposed dated or fussy.  When it came to me (“It was ‘oh, boy’!  Can you believe it?”) they were amazed. “We say that all the time.  Oh, boy.”

Comment: @MJD Interesting, whether this phrase is dated is somehow controversial on ELL :).

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The expression is not even that dated, e.g. [here](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt8135044/)'s a movie from 2020 with exact this title, and [there](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1954701/)'s another one from 2012.

In neither case is the title supposed to be a sentence addressed to a male kid. Note that you can also say ["Oh, brother"](https://outpost-daria-reborn.info/ts_ep207.html) (quote from [Daria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daria)) even if you don't have one:

> Daria - (rolls eyes) Oh, brother.
>
> Jake - He calls himself brother? You mean like Brother Ted?
>
> Daria - No, like, "Oh, brother, you're all crazy."

So there's absolutely no reason you couldn't say "oh, boy" when talking to a girl.

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Comment: Yes, the answer is very much to the point.

Comment: It's not even dated at all, at least if you're speaking general US English.  It may not be the latest slang term used by some social sub-group, but that sub-group's equivalent will probably not be understood by people outside that group.

Comment: Exactly. "Oh boy" is an exclamation, and as such, isn't "directed" at anyone.

Comment: Not entirely convinced that a Chinese film from 2020 or German film from 2012 are the final word on current English phrases, however, as a native US-English speaker, it's still in common use in the Midwest US, and is never assumed to be spoken to a male. This gets my +1.

Answer (score 37):

You can, the "boy" in the phrase is not addressed to the person you are speaking to.  (It probably started as a minced oath with "boy" replacing the blasphemous "Jesus" or "God")

There is a well known song by Buddy Holly with lyrics "Oh boy, when you're with me...".

As slang it is a little dated. Buddy Holly's song was from the 1950s

Comment: Do you mean native speakers don't say (or do so only rarely) 'oh boy' today?

Comment: @sundowner personally I use it every so often. I don't use it as a "minced oath" (I'm perfectly fine swearing if the situation calls for it) but I agree that it may have come from that. It can be used to express excitement or annoyance or resignation. I am aware that it sounds a little dated but I don't think people would think it strange that I use it.

Comment: @sundowner I would only say it (as a native BrE speaker) if I was being deliberately ironic or sarcastic.

Comment: As a non-native speaker, I often use it to show my prowess with idioms.

Comment: I still hear that phrase used, and I use it myself, in a few specialized contexts. For instance, if I'm about to start some intricate swift-moving task, I'll say to whoever is around me, male or female, "Oh boy, here we go..."

Comment: It's still commonly used and widely understood. It's found in song lyrics, movies, and TV shows. It's often used like "Oh no" or "Uh oh" as in "Oh boy, here we go again."

Comment: I can say that in Texas, at least, "oh boy" is a common phrase, but only in the negative/ironic sense -- it never indicates excitement, only concern or exhausted resignation.  (That is to say, "We're going to the amusement park." "Oh boy!" sounds very dated, but "Well, we're going to have to work overtime on Saturday." "Oh, *boy*..." is totally normal.)

Comment: @Darth Pseudonym: But in at least some places outside of Texas, it is fairly commonly used in the positive sense, as well as the negative and/or ironic.  The difference being conveyed by intonation, of course.

Answer (score 8):

> Can I say “Oh boy” to a girl?

The best way to understand this issue for an English learner.

When you utter phrases such as ...

- "Fuck!"
- "O-M-G!"
- "Oh Boy!"
- "Wow!
- "Holy Hell!"

... you are ***not addressing anyone***. That speech fragment is not ***directed to*** the person you are talking to.

They are exclamations.

Incidentally: do note that the comments that "Oh Boy" is "dated" are whacky; ignore.

Comment: While it _is_ an exclamation not particularly addressed to anyone (and thus, gender-neutral), keep in mind that that it can either be positive (like "Wow!") or negative (like "Oh, shit!"). You would need more context or to hear the tone of voice to know how it's being used, and likewise, you would need to be careful of your tone of voice when speaking it, to convey the intended message (an exclamation of joy and delight, or of resignation and dismay).

Comment: ? every single exclamation in English, indeed, every single utterly sentence in English, can be either "positive or negative".  ?  every single time you utter anything, in any language, you have to be "careful of the tone of your voice". The question asked is very specific and clear.